# Access IIS Express running on virtual machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, virtual-machine, iis-express

I'm trying to access IIS Express that I have running on a windows virtual machine on my mac. I have tried including an additional binding pointing to the IP of the virtual machine, ive used netsh to allow a url reservation and made sure that the firewalls are not enabled.

After all of this I attempted to run a program in visual studio and access it via the url on my Mac. The page idles for a large amount of time before returning the error that there was "No Route Host"

This is driving me crazy! Does anyone have any suggestions as to what could be causing it?

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Open IIS, and check whether your HTTP website is running on port 80.
2. Ensure above by first browsing your website on windows guest itself.
3. Check connectivity by sending ping from your MAC host to windows guest IP.
4. If above succeeds, perform telnet on port number 80 from MAC host.

You must be able to crack your issue at one of the above points.